# Datepicker JS error tempus-dominus Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, npm, datetimepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

Trying to implement `datepicker`. I'm using `tempus-dominus-bootstrap-4`. I already installed it using `npm` command, it's already in `package.json`. Followed the documentation yet I get an error, I'm not very good with `javascript`.

I get the error of:

> home:139 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

When I place `<script src="/js/app.js"></script>` above the js function, this is the error I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

**blade.php, the script is inside the `blade` file.**

```
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label for="name">Employee Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="" class="form-control">
                <label for="datetimepicker4">Date Hired</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker4" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker4"/>
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker4" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                        <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**script**

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
        format: 'L'
    });
});
```

Comment: Your script is in `<head>` or just above `</body>` ?

Comment: just above the `</body>` tag @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: Can you wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){})` and try?

Comment: still the same @PrafullaKumarSahu :(

Comment: Can you post updated code? or set it up in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I edited the code, kindly check it @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199732/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-kwestionable).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
            format: 'L'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: still having the error of `$(...).datetimepicker is not a function`

Comment: plesae add jquery.min.js first..i edit my answer.please check

Comment: should i place it in the `head` tag?

Comment: `app.js` already contains jquery, so you should not add again.

Answer (score 0):

In `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
```

Just above `</body>` tag

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
            format: 'L'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<head>` section just add below code. It's working for me-

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
```